# Java server for ajax request

Tags: java, ajax, web-services, soap, comet

I have to start to develop a server, using java, that have to communicate (every few second) well with ajax but not only with it. I read a lot of articles but i'm bit confused because there 's a jungle of different technologies. which is the best choice? Could you suggest me a point of start?

Answer (score 1):

**From a server's point of view, an ajax request is just another request**, and in good possibility, the server wouldn't even know whether a request was an ajax-request. Hence any web-server of choice should suffice your cause. For e.g. jetty, tomcat, etc.

Comment: First of all thanks for reply,
I've already developed a server using Java sockets however i had some issues.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341486/communication-issue-between-java-server-socket-and-javascript-page-jquery-by

so I change approach and i'm going to restart developing server and what i'd like to understand is why a technology is better than others

Answer (score 1):

Just a few hints: Use [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/), which is both a WebServer and a  ServletContainer (it is also well suited for comet). Then, look for tutorials about Servlets. Do you have to use plain HTML/CSS/Ajax on the clientside? If not, have a look at [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/).

**EDIT**

What do you mean by *Develop a Server*? I would bet what you meant was developing a Service.